# MySQL on Western Digital NAS

Tags: mysql, nas

A [WD MyCloud](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C7JIO5Y) device:

```
root@WDMyCloud root # uname -a 
Linux WDMyCloud 3.10.39 #1 SMP Fri Aug     5 11:16:40 CST 2016 2014T20p4 Build-git3f24b4d armv7l GNU/Linux

root@WDMyCloud root # cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.39 (kman@kmachine) (gcc version 4.6.4 (Linaro GCC branch-4.6.4. Marvell GCC Dev 201310-2126.3d181f66 64K MAXPAGESIZE ALIGN) ) #1 SMP Fri Aug 5 11:16:40 CST 2016 2014T20p4 Build-git3f24b4d

root@WDMyCloud root # free -m
         total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:        514528       483616        30912            0        72096
-/+ buffers:             411520       103008
Swap:      2097056            0      2097056
```

If there is enough hardware to run a simple instance of MySQL, how do I get on track (reference to a procedure) to setting up the appropriate repository?

If an instance of MySQL is already running, how would I verify?  This would be ideal because I would like to create a simple data table.

## UPDATE

```
root@WDMyCloud root # service mysqld status
-sh: service: not found

root@WDMyCloud root # service
-sh: service: not found

root@WDMyCloud root # ps aux | grep mysqld
 2771 root      2560 S    {mysqld_safe} /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=root --datadir=/mnt/HD_a4/.@database@
 2868 root     27840 S    /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/mnt/HD_a4/.@database@ --user=root --log-error=/                                mnt/HD_a4/.@database@/WDMyCloud.err --pid-file=/mnt/HD_a4/.@database@/WDMyCloud.pid
25280 root      2592 S    grep mysqld

root@WDMyCloud root # netstat -tunlep | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9612       2868/mysqld
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It has enough resources to run a simple `MySQL` server.

Which Operating System are you using? OS has specific command to check whether a service is running or not. MySQL server may be `mysqld` or `mariadb` in Fedora based system. You can check like this

```
service mysqld status
service mariasb status
```

Another way is check using `ps aux | grep mysqld` and `ps aux| grep mariadb`.

MySQL server bind over TCP port `3306`. You can check any service is listening on that socket or not as follows

```
netstat -tunlep | grep 3306
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions: Test results are posted at the end of the original posting.  The next step is to find the default username and password.  I though "uname - a" would provide the Linux distro, but it is unclear to me.